# Why I can't position flex items in my flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a 3 flexboxes and flex items inside of them. I need them to be on the left, like on the following image:
[image]

But for some reason my image and header are stuck on the right, and can't even be aligned with align-items.
So I have the following result:
[image]

I'm not really sure what's the problem here, I tried to do float:left for image, but it doesn't move.

art_container is a huge container, inside of which are 3 flexboxes - art_block, and flex items inside of them.

```css
.article img{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

.art_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  /* transform: translateY(30%) translateX(30%); */
  width: 100vh;
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.art_block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.art_block img {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.art_block h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<article class="article">
    <div class="art_container">
      <div class="art_block" id="block1">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
        <h2>Sony's new releases for 2018</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="art_block" id="block2">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
        <h2>10 tips to be a better gamer</h2>
      </div>
      
      <div class="art_block" id="block3">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
        <h2>Microsoft has some new tips</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Edit: so i've found that i have another image style for outside container, which i guess may affect my flex image:

```
.article img{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

So that's a style for a bigger div, inside of which is my art_container, and now i'm wondering, how could i make .art_container img style, while not being affected by .article img style?

Comment: In your art_block class why you center vertically and horizontally?

Comment: Why are you setting the width of your container to the _height_ of the screen? (If you're looking for 100% width, use `100%`. Using `vw` is problematic with respect to scrollbars.)

Comment: @Sfili_81 well, i actually tried different kinds of aligning, but neither seemed to work, so i decided to stop on center

Comment: @isherwood so should i change my art_container width to vw instead of vh?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+F5; I'm guessing your layout will change. What you've shared here does not match the output in your screenshot in terms of stuff being 'stuck on the right', so either caching is to blame or you have code you haven't included here.

Comment: @TylerH i've cleared the cache but it stays the same, so i'm not sure that's the problem
but i've included all styles, of this container

Comment: Sometimes the best approach in cases like this is to start over. Build from outside in, one level at a time, paying close attention at each step to what has changed. You probably have more CSS than you need, and it's causing you headaches. Your layout isn't so complicated that this would take more than a few minutes.

Comment: @Carl That's the missing code (plus the markup you didn't edit in); I've updated your question to be a [mcve] which includes that code, now when you run the Snippet you can see the layout matches your screenshot in terms of element positioning. You could fix the issue by adding `position: relative` to `art_block .img`, but there are probably better solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the best strategy is just to step back and simplify. I'm not sure why you have all the fixed sizing on the images and containers, but that's probably not necessary. If you have minimum sizes in mind, use other means to ensure that, such as wrapping to vertical using media queries. The more you stay flexible the simpler your layout will be.

Here's a start.

```css
.art_block {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.art_block img {
  flex: none;
  max-width: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 15px;
}

.art_block h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="art_container">
  <div class="art_block" id="block1">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <h2>Sony's new releases for 2018</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="art_block" id="block2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <h2>10 tips to be a better gamer</h2>
  </div>
  
  <div class="art_block" id="block3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <h2>Microsoft has some new tips</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `flex-wrap: no-wrap;` so your image and text remains on the same line.
I've add a `wrapper` for your text so you can add some `p` tags inside

```css
.art_container {
  position: relative;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  /* transform: translateY(30%) translateX(30%); */
  width: 100%;
  height: 110vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.art_block {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;/* use this */
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.art_block img {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}


.art_block h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="art_container">
  <div class="art_block" id="block1">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <h2>Sony's new releases for 2018</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="art_block" id="block2">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <h2>10 tips to be a better gamer</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="art_block" id="block3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <div class="wrap-text">
      <h2>Microsoft has some new tips</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi! i added nowrap tag, but for some reason image stays on the right

Comment: Check if you have some css rules overidding the images rules

Comment: i've added more detailes to original post, my img class actually was overridden, so now i wonder how could i make two separate img classes?

Comment: the right:0 set the position to the right... you have to adjust this due to your design